# GA Multi Channel Funnels Reporting Python errors

Tags: python, google-analytics-api

I have successfully be able to query data from Google Analytics with the python exemple available on G web site using `reports().batchGet()`

Now I have to do the same with the multi channel funnel (mcf).

Everything I can see on StackO or anywhere else is to call `service.data().mcf().get()`. But then I got the error `AttributeError: 'Resource' object has no attribute 'service'`.

I think it's the way I build my request but using the google `apiclient` the same way I did before I don't know what I have wrong.

Here a sample of the way I init this call :

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']
KEY_FILE_LOCATION = 'client_secrets.json'

def initialize_analytics_reporting():
    """
    Initializes an Analytics Reporting API V4 service object.
    :return: An authorized Analytics Reporting API V4 service object.
    """
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
        KEY_FILE_LOCATION, SCOPES)

    # Build the service object.
    analytics = build('analyticsreporting', 'v4', credentials=credentials)

    return analytics

def get_report(analytics, next_token):
    """
    Queries the Analytics Reporting API V4.
    Args:
      analytics: An authorized Analytics Reporting API V4 service object.
    Returns:
      The Analytics Reporting API V4 response.
    """
    print(analytics.__dict__)
    if next_token == 0:
        return analytics.data.mcf().get(..)
    [...]
```

NOT FOR FUTUR ME OR OTHER :

```
analytics = build('analytics', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
```

Working!

Answer (score 2):

You can pull data using below code:

```
def initialize_mcf_analyticsreporting():
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
        KEY_FILE_LOCATION, SCOPES)
    analytics = build('analytics', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
    mcf_service = analytics.data().mcf()
    return mcf_service

mcf_service = initialize_mcf_analyticsreporting()

report = mcf_service.get(
        start_date=start_date,
        end_date=end_date,
        metrics='mcf:totalConversions,mcf:totalConversionValue',
        ids='ga:xxxxxxx', #Your View ID to replaced by xxxxxxx
        dimensions="mcf:sourceMediumPath,mcf:campaignPath",
        max_results=10000
).execute()
```

You may refer to Google's Documentation here https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/mcf/v3/mcfDevGuide
for additional information.