# Google Analytics MCF API

Tags: python, google-analytics-api

Im trying to use the below class to help build API calls to google analytics.

```
 apiclient.discovery import build
```

It looks pretty plug and play so I figured I would tyr and use the same thing when I want to call the MultiChannelFunnel api. I altered the below code to say 'mcf', 'analytics#mcfData' as well as a couple of other iterations, instead of "analyticsreporting" (as thats what it is for the core reporting).

```
def initialize_analyticsreporting():
  credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
      KEY_FILE_LOCATION, SCOPES)

  analytics = build('mcf', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
  return analytics
```

And of course Im getting errors about bad names. I cant seem to find anywhere in the documentation what the actual service name is (the documentation for build() says the param name is service name, here is a link: https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/epy/googleapiclient.discovery-pysrc.html#build )

So my questions are:

1. Does anyone know the service name for the mcf api from google analytics?
2. Do I have to try a different approach for calling this api? I suspect this might sadly be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi channel funnel reports are a sub-service of the Analytics API. So you can just do something along these lines:

```py
analytics_api = build('analytics', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
mcf_service = analytics_api.data().mcf()

start_date = str(datetime.date(2022, 1, 1))
end_date = str(datetime.date.today())

report = mcf_service.get(
    start_date=start_date,
    end_date=end_date,
    metrics='mcf:totalConversions,mcf:totalConversionValue',
    ids='ga:12345'
).execute()
```

Comment: credentials = './credential.json'
analytics_api = build('analytics', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

Error: 'str' object has no attribute 'authorize'

Does anybody knows how to import credentials from json file?

Comment: You can use the [`Credentials.from_authorized_user_file()`](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/google.oauth2.credentials.html#google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials.from_authorized_user_file) method to load the credentials.

Comment: Thanks, this snippet finally worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74306435/10533376